Stochastic process of coin toss winrate
Consider a game tossing a fair coin infinitely, and the player wins with heads. The game starts from $1:1$, so the starting win rate is $\frac{1}{2}$.
Now let the variable $p$ be the overall win rate, expressed in irreducible fractions. Consider the stochastic process where the state is the value of $p$, changing after each coin toss. Its possible states are all rational numbers in $(0,1)$.
My question is: Is this process transient, null recurrent or positive recurrent? This is not quite a Markov process, and I'm not familiar with relevant tools.
Edit: I find the state $\frac{1}{2}$ null recurrent. This occurs when the win difference is $0$. It is a well known result that this will return with prob. $1$, with infinite expectation returning time.

I think you need to first accurately define "this process"

@VezenBU edited

Rather than the process, you might try to distinguish the states as transient (positive probability of never returning), null recurrent (probability $1$ of returning but infinite expectation of time of next return) or positive recurrent (probability $1$ of returning  and a finite expectation of time of next return), as the analysis may be different for $\frac12$ compared to other proportions.  What have you tried?

OK.  So you have edited the question saying you find the state $\frac12$ null recurrent.  I suspect all the other states are transient: for example, I think the probability of ever visiting $\frac23$ is $\phi-1=0.618034$, and assuming you visit it after the first step the conditional probability of ever visiting again is $3-\frac32\phi=0.572949$, and it only gets smaller from there.

@Henry Would you like to show how you got those results?

@MaYe The probability of ever visiting $\frac23$ is: $\frac12$ to first visit at $(2,1)$, $\frac1{16}$ to first visit at $(4,2)$ avoiding $(2,1)$, $\frac{3}{128}$ to first visit $(6,3)$ avoiding $(2,1)$ and $(4,2)$, etc.; the probability of first visiting $\frac23$ at $(2k,k)$ avoiding the previous points is $\dfrac{3k-3 \choose k-1}{(2k-1)2^{3k-2}}$, and if you add these all up you will get $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\approx 0.618034$.
